# C <Address 0x53 out of bounds> error

Tags: c, indexoutofboundsexception

```
void findWay(int column,int sum,char *array,int s,stack_t sta)
{
 if(array[s+column+2]=='0')
{
```

When I debug program, I am getting an error which is "Address 0x53 out of bounds" (if(maze[s+column+2]=='0') at this line). Why?

Someone please help me.

Comment: What is the size of the array ?

Answer (score 3):

Because `s+column+2` exceeds the bounds of the array, you need to allocate more memory for `array` or make sure you don't step outside the allocated memory.

Comment: As i said, 0x53 seems pretty close to zero. I dont think his problem is with the size of the array, but the value of it (wich I'm pretty sure is zero in this case)

Answer (score 2):

When using `var[]`, you dereference `*var` pointer. Here, as 0x53 is close to zero, it seems that `array` is NULL. When accessing `array[s+column+2]` you add `(s+column+2) * sizeof(*array)` to zero, wich certainly result to `0x53`.

You can verify this printing `array` value with `printf("pointer value : %p\n", array);`.

Comment: it could be an offset, but anyway +1

Comment: No, array is not NULL because the program can print elements of the array.

Comment: Did you try in this particular function ?

Answer (score 1):

Out of bound always means only one thing, **out of the allowed boundary**.
So when you get an *address* out of bound it means the *address* is outside the boundary. This boundary can be defined by program, array.

Answer (score 0):

It means the value of `s+column+2` is larger than the length of the array.